# GCP Monitoring External Service Call Status Code Written In Log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a service in GKE that calls External Service. My service logs the status code received from the External Service in the stdout log.

The log format in the GCP Logs Explorer will be similar like below

```
{
  insertId: "ohgmgx7zz6nhgf9m"
  jsonPayload: {
     serviceUrl: 'https://example.com',
     response: {
        statusCode: 500
     }
  }
}
```

I want to have a GCP Monitoring Dashboard in Google Monitoring that will monitor the statusCode count. Something like below.

[image]

I also want to be able to have alarm policies in GCP Monitoring that raise when a certain statusCode (e.g. 5XX) raise above the threshold.

How do I do that?

Comment: We have a service in GCP called Dashboards which lets us view and analyze data from different sources in the same context.We can customize the dashboard to get our desired chart displayed.Go to dashboards under Monitoring and click on create dashboard and then select line in chart library for the time series data to get displayed. Here in basic select the resource and other details and go to MQL and custom the query as per the requirement.Refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples?authuser=1&_ga=2.203221207.-73834405.1615878405#qlx-ratios)for details on MQL

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you're after is called "logs-based metrics":

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics

You'll need to create a counter metric using your response code field as a label.